# How do I uninstall a program with C#.NET with VS Express 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express

I have VS 2008 Express (.NET 3.5) and currently have no way to elegantly uninstall my program whenever I publish an update. Right now people are using the program outside of my network (so I can't point them to some intranet folder to check for updates, and checking an internet site is no good either). There are frequent updates (for reasons too complicated to go into here) and they constantly need to be using Add/Remove programs to uninstall then reinstall. Is there a way to have a Start Menu option to uninstall my program? Surely there must be, I'm a novice at C# (just moved from VBA) so I'm still learning the options.  Thanks

Comment: One suggestion that could resolve this in the future is to build in patch-like updates for your program. This way, both the user and the program would not have to worry about uninstalling and reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at 'Click Once Deployment'? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).aspx

It would allow your users to get updates as they are released as well as uninstall through add/remove programs.

Comment: From my understanding ClickOnce allows an instance of the program to look to some directory on a server for a newer version. However, my situation doesn't permit that. (unless there is a way for CLickOnce to look at the users computer for the updated file? is that possible?) What I can do is give The user a new file, let them open it, and ideally the file would install over top the old version. Right now it spits out an error when I try to install over the old version.

Answer (score 0):

If you use full Visual Studio, then you can create a Setup project which will create an Install/Uninstall EXE for you.

If not, then I guess you'll have to write your own installer, or maybe add some batch files to install or uninstall your program.

Comment: If I do us a batch file how do I tell it to run first? Would the use have to open the batch file and the bat would open the exe after it has uninstaller the previous version?

Comment: You would not tell the batch file to run first... Your documentation file, which you supply, would tell the user to run which batch file to install and which to uninstall. It's not ideal but then VS Express is intended for hobby programs only. If you upgrade to full Visual Studio you can use that system's features or the WIX platform to generate installers.